# tee stdout and stderr independently, without adding jitter

Tags: python, bash, posix, file-descriptor, output-buffering

I'd like to create a command wrapper that records a log of stderr and stdout, separately, without changing the output of the command. One aspect of not changing the output is to ensure that the ordering of output on stderr vs stdout isn't changed.

I've created a synthetic worst-case scenario: (`python -u` puts the interpreter into fully-unbuffered mode)

```
$ cat outputter.py
from sys import stdout, stderr

for line in range(10):
    from itertools import izip, cycle
    for column, char, file in izip(
            range(79),
            cycle(('_', '|')),
            cycle((stdout, stderr)),
    ):
        file.write(char)
    stdout.write('\n')

$ python -u outputter.py
_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_
_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_
_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_
_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_
_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_
_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_
_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_
_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_
_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_
_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_
```

I can keep a record of the two streams and redirect them back to their original destinations fairly easily with a little bash, but the interleaving gets destroyed:

```
$ python -u outputter.py > >(tee stdout.txt) 2> >(tee stderr.txt >&2)
|||_____________||||||||||_||___||_|__|||___||_|_||__||___||_||___||_|_|__||__|
__||__||_|__||_||___||_|_|_|__||__||__||_|__||_||___||__||_|_|__||_||__|__||_|_
__||__||_|__||_||___||__||_|_|_|__||_||__||___||_|__||__||__||__||_|_|___|||_|_
__|_||__||_||___||__||__||_|__||_|__||__||_||___||_|_||___||_|__||_|__||_|__||_
__|__|||_||___||_|__||_|_|__||__||_|__||_|_|___||||___||_|__||__||_||___|||___|
_|___||||___|||___||_|__|||__|_||___|||__|_||___|||___||_|__|||__||__|__||__||_
_|_||__|__|||__|_||___|||___|||___|||__|_|||____|||___||||___|_|||____|||___||_
_|__|||__|__|||__|__|||__|__|||___|||___||_|__|||__|__||_|__||_|_||___||_|__||_
_||___|||___||||___|_||___||_|__|||__||__||__|_||__||__|_|||___||___||_||__||__
_|__||_||___|||___|||__|_||__|||___||___|||___|||___||_|__||__|||___|||__|_||__
```

The results are actually highly variable:

```
$ python -u outputter.py > >(tee stdout.txt) 2> >(tee stderr.txt >&2)
_______________|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||_______________________||||||__
__||||____|||____|||||_____||||____|||||____|||||______||||____||||_____|||||__
_||||||||__________|||||_____||||____|||||____|||___||||_____|||||_____|||||___
_|||_____||||____||||||______|||||_____||||||_____||||_____|||||_____|||||____
|_______|||||||||____||||_____||||____|||||______|||||____|||||_____|||||____||_
||_____||||____|||||_____|||||_____||||____||||____||||___||||____||||____|||__
___|||||____|||||_____||||____|||____|||||_____|||||_____|||||_____||||____|||_
__||||_____||||____|||||_____|||||____||||_____|||||_____||||____||||____||||__
__|||____||||____||||____|||||____|||||_____||||_____||||||_____||||_____||||__
_||____|||||_____||||____|||||____||||____||||_____|||||_____||||____|||||____
|

$ python -u outputter.py > >(tee stdout.txt) 2> >(tee stderr.txt >&2)
_|||||||_______|_|||____|||__|_|__|||__|_||___|||___||_|___||||___|||__||___||_
________________________________________
________________________________________
________________________________________
________________________________________
________________________________________
________________________________________
________________________________________
________________________________________
________________________________________
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

My question is: is there any conceivable way to do this and also preserve the interleaving of the original streams?

Also, why doesn't the terminal have this same problem? Any implementation I can imagine would have this same issue.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that.  And it isn't because of buffering, this will produce the same random result:

```
python -u outputter.py > >(cat -u >&2) 2> >(cat -u >&2)
```

The problem is your shell needs to write to two pipes, and it uses `select(2)` to choose which pipe to write to.  Since there is no danger of filling any pipe buffer, both pipes are "equally available" for writing, and this creates a race condition between the two `cat`s: the one that finishes first writing a character wins.  The result of the race depends on the scheduler and on what's going on at that very moment in the system.  Thus the randomness.

On a side note: if the problem were related to buffering you'd have gotten the result garbled the same way every time.

Comment: This implies the terminal does its job without using select(2). How does that work? Can't my app do the same?

Comment: @bukzor After some more pondering I edited my answer, hoppefully I got it right now.  The race is which `cat` gets to finish first writing a character, not which `fd` the shell gets to write to.  If you don't redirect the output there are no other processes, and thus no cat fight. :) You still can't fix it, the very existence of two processes racing to write to the terminal creates the problem.

Comment: What if it were one process with an event loop? I'm not actually going to use cat/tee for this; it will be a python wrapper script.

Comment: @bukzor If my theory above is correct a single process should be fine.  As soon as the initial application use different buffering methods for `stdout` and `stderr`, things would break again.  The safer thing to do would be to make everything line-buffered, but you need to control all applications involved, and write only full lines to both `stdout` and `stderr`.

Comment: @bukzor Actually, it isn't trivial even with a single process and everything unbuffered.  I'd say a single `select()` to decide which `fd` to read from wouldn't work.  You might have a better chance if you try non-blocking reading of a single character alternatively from each `fd`.  Basically what you do for writing but in reverse.

Comment: That's what makes me ask "Why doesn't the terminal have this issue?" It's not a magical process, yet it has overcome what seems to be an inherent race.

Comment: @bukzor The terminal doesn't read from multiple `fd`s.  The shell redirects the `stdout` and `stderr` of your program according to the command line.  If both are supposed to go to the terminal, the shell redirects both to the terminal's input.  The terminal ultimately sees a single stream of characters, and displays them in the order it receives them.  At least that's how I understand it.  So basically what's going in the terminal case is that `stdout` and `stderr` are ultimately pointing to the same device.  Buffering breaks this because it happens at a higher layer (before the data is sent).